# CoreML: iOS: How to get 2D coordinates of center of detected model

Tags: xcode, machine-learning, computer-vision, arkit, coreml

I want to find the 2d coordinate system for the detected model so that I can raycast and get the 3d coordinate system.

I am doing following steps

1. Microsoft customvision.ai to train the models so that it can be detected with iOS CoreML
2. Download my .mlmodel file from custom vision and load it in Xcode project
3. Use vision framework in Xcode to the models.

Up till this, I am able to identify the model and get the probability also. However, I am having the challenge to identify the center point of the detected model, based on which I want to overlay information on top of it.

Please suggest if there are any supported frameworks available to identify the model coordinates with respect to screen coordinates.

Typically, when following image is detected, it should identify the the center of the detected target. I have drawn red bounding box for reference.[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture that color code the probability of object within a typical camera frame? Depending on what you have right now, there are several approaches.

Comment: Hi, i have attached image in the actual post.

Comment: Can you attach a few cases where the center of the bounding box not being a good solution?

Comment: I can detect the model with probability. How ever how do i know the model center? So that i can raycast and get the 3d scnvector3 coordinates

Comment: From the image space, knowing the center of the detected model bounding box gives you a line of where the possible model center is in 3d space. Without knowing more info such as location between camera and object, it's not possible to get an exact 3d. If you know the real life size of the gear, you can narrow down the range of where the point is.

Answer (score 1):

CustomVision models return VNClassificationobservation which doesn't contain position of the current detected object
i would recommend to train your model with Object detection from Turicreate which produces VNRecognizedObjectObservation which contains the coordinates of the detected Object

see also:- https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/object_detection/

Comment: Is this just for mac? Not for iOS?